# BroadcastReceiver does not receiver TIME_SET, DATE_CHANGED actions

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I try catch date and time changing. For this I registered receive

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".model.ChangeTimeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.DATE_CHANGED"/>
                <action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.TIME_SET"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

But method `onRecive()` is not called by system

Code of my receiver

```
public class ChangeTimeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ChangeTimeReceiver", "onReceive")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Action identifiers are case sensitive, try this:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".model.ChangeTimeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
    </intent-filter>
```